# Consider Publish/Subscribe rules outside of templates (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have an app where each User has a Counter object associated with it. The User is subscribed to the corresponding Counter.

Each time a user submits the form, I want to save the current value of the User's Counter to the form. However, the client and server disagree on what Counter object to use.

```
Counters = new Mongo.Collection("counters");
Router.route('/register', { name: 'insertRegistration',
    waitOn: function() {
      return [ Meteor.subscribe('counters') ];
    },
});
RegistrationSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    somevalue: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function() {
            console.log(Counters.findOne()); // Different results on client and server
            return "whatever";
        }
    }
});
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('counters', function() { 
        return Counters.find({ user_id: this.userId });
    });
}
```

`Counters.findOne()` on the client picks the Counter object associated with the current user.
`Counters.findOne()` on the server picks a Counter object out of the collection of all Counter objects.

I think this is because the Client asks for `Counters` and gets what it's subscribed to, while Server asks for `Counters` and gets the Collection.

Is there a way to consider the publish/subscribe rules on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server, do

```
Counter.findOne({ user_id: this.userId })
```

to get the correct counter for the user.

Comment: Your solution works, but this would repeat the rules in two places. (Although, I suppose there's probably a way to abstract the rules.) I was kind of hoping for a way to accomplish this through subscribe/publish, but this way will do, I guess. - Especially if it's the only way.

Comment: What Publish and subscribe mechanism is for client only. On server, the access is unrestricted thus the filtering has to be done manually. Any method you write on a server that deals with an _id of any kind will require that _id to be provided by the client.